# ZeroClipboard: Hiding element when there is no Flash in browser

Tags: javascript, flash, zeroclipboard

Using ZeroClipboard, as the page loads, I want to hide the "copy to clipboard" button if there is no Adobe Flash  present.

I understand that there are *noflash* and *wrongflash* events, but I wonder if these can be used to effect the rendering of the page so that the button can't even be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a button with something like:

```
var $button = $('.btn'),
    client = new ZeroClipboard($button);
```

you could do something like

```
client.on("error", function(e) {
     client.destroy();
     $button.hide();
}
```